# What does assigning a struct's variable actually do?

Tags: c, variables, struct

I'm writing a pandemic simulation as a way of learning C and I'm trying to use a struct called Person to organize all of my data under single items. My issue arises when I try to check if one of the struct's values is greater than 100 and then assign another attribute a value.

This is the struct I'm working off of:

```
struct Person {
    double levelOfInfection;
    int cleared;
};
```

This is the code that isn't working as intended.

```
void checkForClearance(struct Person targetPerson) {
    double val = (double)targetPerson.levelOfInfection - 100.0; // checking if the level of infection is over 100
    printf("%f\n",val); // debug print statement
    if (val >= 0) { // if over 100 set cleared to 1
        targetPerson.cleared = 1;
    } else { // if less that 100 set cleared to 0
        targetPerson.cleared = 0;
    }
}
```

My question is that I don't understand what assigning a value to a struct attribute does? Since it doesn't seem to work as a variable does. If someone could provide some insight on what is actually happening when I write `targetPerson.cleared = 1;` that would be of great help.

Comment: It assigns the value to the *copy of the `struct`* that was passed, not to the caller's `struct`. After function return the whole copy is discarded.

Comment: You are just working with a copy of your struct in your function. If you want to clear the real values you need to work with a pointer to the struct in your function

Comment: Members *do* work like variables. As for what's happening: usually nothing. The variable's local and the assigned value isn't used so an optimizing compiler is free to delete all the code after the printf. If you had passed in a pointer instead then `targetPerson->cleared = x;` would have set an `int`-sized (in this case) piece of memory at offset `offsetof(struct Person,cleared)` to `x`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks for the tip.

Comment: `(double)targetPerson.levelOfInfection` <- Why the cast?

Comment: I didnt know if it was a type error at first and just left it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the copy of the struct. You can do what you want in two ways:

---

Using pointers (note the `->` operator instead of `.`):

```c
void checkForClearance(struct Person* targetPerson) {
    double val = (double)targetPerson->levelOfInfection - 100.0; // checking if the level of infection is over 100
    printf("%f\n",val); // debug print statement
    if (val >= 0) { // if over 100 set cleared to 1
        targetPerson->cleared = 1;
    } else { // if less that 100 set cleared to 0
        targetPerson->cleared = 0;
    }
}
```

Returning the modified copy:

```c
struct Person checkForClearance(struct Person targetPerson) {
    double val = (double)targetPerson.levelOfInfection - 100.0; // checking if the level of infection is over 100
    printf("%f\n",val); // debug print statement
    if (val >= 0) { // if over 100 set cleared to 1
        targetPerson.cleared = 1;
    } else { // if less that 100 set cleared to 0
        targetPerson.cleared = 0;
    }
    return targetPerson;
}
```

note that if you are doing it this way then you need to reassign the new value after calling:

```c
person = checkForClearance(person);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm still learning C so sorry if this was a redundant question.

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY-s7O0FiYE&list=PL8TdH6gRQnLtmVxAamBznCrfFWWaF9_8x&ab_channel=NareshiTechnologies) Playlist explains pointers pretty well

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
void checkForClearance(struct Person *ptargetPerson) {
    double val = (double)ptargetPerson->levelOfInfection - 100.0; // checking if the level of infection is over 100
    printf("%f\n",val); // debug print statement
    if (val >= 0) { // if over 100 set cleared to 1
        ptargetPerson->cleared = 1;
    } else { // if less that 100 set cleared to 0
        ptargetPerson->cleared = 0;
    }
}
```